# Remove focus from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, focus, html-input

How can I remove focus from canvas and give it to input fields in my HTML? Currently the canvas retains focus even though I'm actively clicking on HTML text inputs. Therefore it is actually impossible to even write something into them.

Ideally it would lose focus when my mouse is outside of the `div` it is in.

Comment: Can you share some code? Do you have a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.com) that shows this particular problem?

Comment: I have a lot of code, not sure what to post. I'm using requestAnimationFrame for the main function.

Comment: Is it possible that you have your HTML text inputs inside the `<canvas>` tags? If so, move them outside of it.

Comment: Nope, that is not the case. I'll post the part of the HTML which is relevant.

Comment: Is it a misstake by you when reducing your code or is there a ´>` missing at the end of your last <input>-tag, after value=""?

Comment: Might you have CSS that is causing the canvas to lay overtop of the form fields?  I threw the code you gave into jsFiddle and I was able to click on the input fields.

Comment: @Niddro it was missing, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @haltersweb added CSS to the question.

Comment: The reason you can't touch the text fields is probably because the canvas is covering it. Set the background color of the canvas to red and you'll see it. In the CSS file `canvas {background-color: red;}`

Comment: @Niddro no, it is not covering it. Look at EDIT 6.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Had this in my IO.js file...

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event)
{   
    event.preventDefault(); // This prevented focus on the input fields..
    // Mouse button clicked
    switch (event.which)
    {
        case 1:
            // Left Mouse button pressed.
            mouse.left = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            // Middle Mouse button pressed.
            mouse.middle = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            // Right Mouse button pressed.
            mouse.right = true;
            break;
    }

});
```

Really stupid problem, sorry to bother you with it.